# How to create a defconfig file from a .config?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kbuild, archlinux-arm

I have done `make menuconfig` for a board `defconfig` and modified few configurations. When I select save, a new `.config` was created in the Kernel top directory.

I want to create new `defconfig` for this `.config` file created.

Can I copy the `.config` as a new `defconfig` and copy to `arch/arm/configs/`?

```
$ cp .config arch/arm/configs/board_new_defconfig
```

Comment: Yes, copying the file would work. But as `defconfig's` are know to have minimal configurations of the board it is better to remove few of the `CONFIG_XXXXXX` that are not arbitrary for you board

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/439511/how-to-save-or-export-a-custom-linux-kernel-configuration

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you have to do just one command and use the created file as you want to.

```
% make savedefconfig 
% cp defconfig arch/arm/configs/my_cool_defconfig
```

(Pay attention to the [filename template](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/kconfig/Makefile#L93) that is used for *defconfig*)

To get all possible targets just run

```
% make help
```

As noted by [Adam Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337526/adam-miller) followed by [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1588913/jeremy), users of Buildroot distribution can use wrappers for that purpose, i.e. (per Buildroot manual, [section 8.1](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#make-tips)):

- **linux-savedefconfig** for `Linux` kernel
- **barebox-savedefconfig** for `barebox` bootloader
- **uboot-savedefconfig** for `U-Boot` bootloader

`make savedefconfig` [minimizes the generated `defconfig`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/scripts/kconfig/confdata.c#L665) skipping redundant configs that are implied by others.

Comment: Ha! I use my_kool_<foo> as a meta variable, myself!

Comment: What about linux-savedefconfig? Aren't those discrete defconfigs, one for buildroot and all the accessory packages, one for the linux kernel itself?

Comment: You can do:

make linux-savedefconfig - as per the buildroot manual. I would think that make linux-menuconfig and linux-savedefconfig correspond just as menuconfig and savedefconfig targets do, no?

Comment: Please note that after this defconfig generated will be sorted but not sorted in alphabetic order

Comment: @ashish, why do we need it sorted at all? The order currently is the order of appearance in Kconfig:s.

Comment: "make linux-savedefconfig" is only useful if you are using "buildroot" to build embedded linux, which the OP did not mention. However I added +1 to AdamMiller 's comment because this was just what I was looking for, and other buildroot users may end up here.

Comment: @Jeremy, so, `make linux-savedefconfig` is a wrapper in Buildroot for Linux kernel's config, correct? Okay, I'm about to update the answer, thanks!

Comment: @0andriy, yes true but sometimes people expect it to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: @0andriy Hi, I ran `make defconfig` and `make menuconfig` to remove some configs, and `make`. Then I did `make savedefconfig` and copied the new defconfig to arch/arm64/configs/def1config. And I tried `make def1config` but it says "make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'def1config'.  Stop". Can you check if your method still works? (ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf- )

Comment: @ChanKim, yes, it works. Nobody will ever break this fundamental feature of Kbuild.

Comment: @0andriy strange, I tried fresh from linux-5.4.21 code. started with defconfig, and for test, removed PCI, sound driver, SATA driver and built the kernel just to check. and did 'make savedefconfig' and moved the defconfig to arch/arm64/configs/newconfig. When I do 'make newconfig' it gives me the same error.. I can do with saved .config file anyway.

Comment: @ChanKim, sad to be you, I have specifically added this: _"Pay attention to the filename template that is used for defconfig"_.

Comment: @0andriy sorry missed that. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For your platform, in a new defconfig file, yes. In fact this is the safest way to create a new defconfig. If you manually remove config entries from an existing config file to create a new one, you are likely to get dependency issues and during build, it might restart the kernel config and give you prompts for selecting individual config options.