# Why is make savedefconfig removing entries?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I want to add entries to a vendor-provided defconfig for a Yocto distribution. In order to add the new drivers I want, I usually use the following process in my Linux directory:

```
$ cp $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig .config
$ make menuconfig
$ # I select some drivers I want to add and save .config file
$ make savedefconfig
$ cp defconfig $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig
```

The `savedefconfig` step adds my drivers correctly, but is also removing some important drivers that are vendor-provided:

```
$ diff -u $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig defconfig
--- $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig
+++ defconfig
@@ -1,22 +1,11 @@
-CONFIG_FHANDLE=y
 CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
 CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
 CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
 CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
-CONFIG_PERF_EVENTS=y
 CONFIG_MODULES=y
 CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
-CONFIG_ARCH_SUNXI=y
 CONFIG_SMP=y
 CONFIG_NR_CPUS=8
-CONFIG_AEABI=y
-CONFIG_HIGHMEM=y
-CONFIG_ARM_APPENDED_DTB=y
-CONFIG_ARM_ATAG_DTB_COMPAT=y
-CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
-CONFIG_CPUFREQ_DT=y
-CONFIG_VFP=y
-CONFIG_NEON=y
[...]
```

If I understood the `savedefconfig` step well, it is removing options that are already set by default and thus redundant. However removing all these vendor-provided drivers are causing the newly compiled kernel to not boot at all after uboot.

I even tried only the `savedefconfig` step without adding any drivers, and vendor drivers are removed and kernel hangs.

Do you have any idea why `savedefconfig` is removing these entries, and how to make it stop? Currently I have to isolate diff changes by hand and manually add new lines that I am interested in into the Yocto defconfig file.

Comment: You perform `cp defconfig $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig`, and then `diff -u $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig defconfig` shows that **copied** file is not identical... Has some other actions been skipped in your workflow?

Comment: The diff call is started before the last `cp` command in order to compare it to the old defconfig before overriding it. I use this workflow on other Yocto distributions but on this one not because it will loose me vendor drivers.

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't be the case, except perhaps $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig is not used as a real defconfig. In that case, you shoudl avoid `cp defconfig $YOCTO_MYKERNEL/files/defconfig` and instead pick the new options from the new defconfig and put them all manually into the yocto defconfig. I guess that's what you are doing now.

Comment: You may also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899104/creating-defconfig-file-from-config/27918677#27918677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the reason for all of this: I was calling `make savedefconfig` without specifying the ARM architecture, thus I think the build system will remove any non-revevant entries like all the `SUNXI_*` drivers (because they are not used on x86_64).

This call does not mangles important drivers:

```
make ARCH=arm savedefconfig
```

In order to not forget to do this step, one can use the Yocto steps instead that will automatically use the relevant architecture:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel
```

Bitbake will print the path of the generated `defconfig` file that you will have to copy over the older one in order to take the changes into account.